# What's the difference between [1] int{} and [] int{0}

Tags: go

I'm trying to get `array` changed in other `func`, and then return the changed. So I wrote a sample code below, my question is why changes in `changeArr02` function can affect the origin `arr` while `changeArr01` not.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func changeArr01(arr [1]int) {
        arr[0] = -100
}

func changeArr02(arr []int) {
        arr[0] = -200
}

func main() {
        arr01 := [1]int{}
        changeArr01(arr01)
        fmt.Println(arr01) // 0

        arr02 := []int{0}
        changeArr02(arr02)
        fmt.Println(arr02) // -200
}
```

Comment: One is an array, one is a slice. Most basic questions are answered within the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) which only takes a few minutes to finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 arr01 := [1]int{}
```

is an array of integer with the size of 1

```
 arr02 := []int{0}
```

it's a slice of ints with one integer inside (0)

more explained in here:
https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7